# What is a constipation remedy that doesn't give you a headache or raise your blood pressure?

Tags: blood-pressure, headache, constipation

What is a constipation remedy that doesn't give you a headache or raise your blood pressure the way senna, or various salts (magnesium oxide, potassium), or enemas (salts) do?

Comment: [Polyethylene glycol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene_glycol).

Comment: @CountIblis Used to use that but it does raise your blood pressure and give you a headache. In fact, laying on your tummy you can hear the blood pumping through your ears so loud it drowns out other sounds and you go momentarily 'deaf' for several minutes.

Comment: Why not gradually increase the amount of fiber in your diet? You can do that quite easily by reducing the amount of fat and increasing the amount of whole grain carbs. If you keep the amount of calories the same, the mass and volume of food will increase (because carbs contain less than half of the calories of fats per unit mass). And with more food on your plate, you'll want to add some more vegetables too. You should also eat a lot of fruits, [see e.g. here how oranges can help](https://spoonuniversity.com/lifestyle/do-eating-oranges-help-with-pooping).

Comment: I get about 16g of soluble fiber per day via Soylent, on average.